# Google compute engine, How to send 301 to redirect to https

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I want to be able to serve the website always in https. I am not apache specialist but this is how people do it out there:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

code from:
https://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https

Is there a way to do this with GCE? I can only see in the docs forward rules but nothing about redirect.

Thank you

Leo

Comment: These settings don't work on Apache server behind the load balancer. Is there a way to do this from the load balancer itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine allows you to run software, such as Linux and Apache, on Google's hardware by using virtualization to make it look like you have your own dedicated machine.

The above snippet of apache configuration should work if you install it in the Apache configuration on a GCE instance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think there should be a way to do before the loading balance or in the forwarding rules. Somewhere before hit the vm's